# Bundlejs error on release build in Xcode (react-native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, babeljs, react-native-ios

For some reason I am getting the following error when building a release version of my application via react-native.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: t.typeof is not a function. (In 't.typeof("function"==typeof Symbol?Symbol.iterator:"@@iterator")', 't.typeof' is undefined) (/Users/../THEAPP.app/main.jsbundle:11)', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: t.typeof is not a function. (In 't.typeof("function...'

This is the source of the code that has the above error that I found in my bundlejs file:

```
!(function(e){"use strict";var r,t=e.babelHelpers={};t.typeof="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"===t.typeof("function"==typeof Symbol?Symbol.iterator:"@@iterator")?
```

I have tried both of these methods of a release build:

1. Making bundle by editing the Scheme to be a Release bundle
2. Export a bundle myself by using the following: `react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`

I get the same error for both of these. And of course, this is after I change my **AppDelegate.m** to the following:

```
//jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

---

I also followed [someone's response](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19788#issuecomment-399327751) from Github issues and tried the following, but got another separate issue entirely after the fact:

I did:

```
npm uninstall -g babel-preset-env
npm install --save @babel/preset-env
```

Added this to my package.json file

```
 "babel": { "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "react-native"] }
```

And created a `.babelrc` file in my root project with:

```
{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "react-native"] }
```

Then get this on an Xcode build:

[image]

## Environment

- **OS**: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
- **Node**: 9.11.1
- **npm**: 5.6.0
- **Watchman**: 4.9.1
- **Xcode**: Version 9.4 (9F1027a)
- **react**: 16.3.1
- **react-native**: 0.55.4

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by completely restarting my app and using:

```
react-native init PROJECTNAME
```